# How to implement an interface in Fragment from a non parent Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, interface, callback

I have not found a clear solution anywhere on stack for this.

Here's my basic set up

```
public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private OnAttributesUpdatedListener onAttributesUpdatedListener;

    public interface OnAttributesUpdatedListener
    {
        public void onAttributesUpdated();
    }

    public void setTargetFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        this.onAttributesUpdatedListener = (OnAttributesUpdatedListener) fragment;
    }

    private void whenFinishedSomethingCallback()
    {
        onAttributesUpdatedListener.onAttributesUpdated();
    }
}


public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements Activity1.OnAttributesUpdatedListener
{
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(rivalButtonClick == 0)
                {
                    Activity1 activity1 = new Activity1();
                    activity1.setTargetFragment(Fragment1.this);
                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), activity1.getClass()));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I get a null pointer exception and crashes on : `onAttributesUpdatedListener.onAttributesUpdated();` because for some reason my listener never gets set properly. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45954099/421467

Comment: I think you have to reverse your logic.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde that link is for the reverse

Comment: i want to implement the interface in the fragment not in the activity

Comment: @TheQ So please change the title of the question.

Comment: @Mr.Hyde I just updated the question

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the listener at start of the fragment `onCreatView()` or in `onActivityCreated()` only if the Desired `Activity` is a parent `Activity` of that particular fragment. Below is an example .

```
 public class Activity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private OnAttributesUpdatedListener onAttributesUpdatedListener;
    public interface OnAttributesUpdatedListener {
        public void onAttributesUpdated();
    }

    public void setListener(OnAttributesUpdatedListener onAttributesUpdatedListener) {
        this.onAttributesUpdatedListener = onAttributesUpdatedListener;
    }

    private void whenFinishedSomethingCallback() {
        if(onAttributesUpdatedListener!=null)
        onAttributesUpdatedListener.onAttributesUpdated();
    }
}


 public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements Activity1.OnAttributesUpdatedListener
{
    @Override
    public void onAttributesUpdated() {
        // Do your stuff here
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ((Activity1)getActivity()).setListener(this);
    }
}
```

Read about fragment Life cycle to make use of `getActivity()`. also remove the listener when fragment is destroyed .

**Use [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) for communicating between in case the `Fragment` exists in other `Activity`.**

Comment: my app crashes when I override onActivityCreated. I was a bit unclear, Activity1 is not the parent of the Fragment, Activity1 is completely separate from the fragment

Comment: notice in my code, i use an intent to start Activity1

Comment: Thats what i mentioned in first place . You can only access the parent activity from fragment . So accept it your question is misleading . Anyway you can use `LocalBroadcast` for this purpose .

Comment: You doing great, I will trying keep up to your example.

Answer (score 0):

At first create an Interface like this:

`public interface Listener{
      void doSomething() }`

Then implement this interface in your activity.

And also add

```
Listener listener
```

In your fragment
And in  onAttach method in fragment use this

```
listener=(Listener)activity
```

Then call listener whenever you need .